# PowerBi Dashboard - Percentage format for decimal numbers

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a Dashboard in Power Bi with source from Kusto Query. The dashoard has a data label which is a decimal number and I have conditional format to highlight the value based on the rules. My issue is I could not apply % symbol for these Data label´s. If I strcat in Kusto Query the value changes to a string and the conditional format does not work.

So I how do I put a % symbol to the values in Dashboard pls . Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the datatype of the column to percent?

Comment: yes I tried this already. It multiplies the value into 100 %. for example if the value is 1 it displays as 100% . where the correct value should be 1%

Comment: You need to give us more details on table data and the calculations you did, else we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second measure based on the original measure: FORMAT([Measure], "0%"), use this measure in the viz and apply conditional formatting based on the original (numeric) measure.

Comment: sorry I didnt get it . can you give like an example or reference link. Do I need to make this change to the Query